# Gradle compile dependency outside of project

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, grpc-java

I have a frontend and a backend repository for my app.  The backend is written in Go and serves the API over gRPC.  The generated gRPC Java files end up in `backend-repo/proto-gen/java/` (so `backend-repo/proto-gen/java/com/myApp/Users.java`).

In my frontend android repo I have submoduled the backend repo to a folder called `server`.  I want to modify my `build.gradle` to compile the `.java` files from the backend.

```
android-repo/
    app/
        build.gradle
    server/proto-gen/java/com/myApp/
        Users.java
        AnotherService.java
```

I'm very new to Android development and am struggling to figure out the right approach.

This is a snippet from my `app/build.gradle` but it fails because it can't find the package `com.google.protobuf`.

```
task compileGrpc (type: JavaCompile) {
    source = fileTree(dir: '../server/proto-gen/java/', include: '**/*.java')
    destinationDir = file('build/classes')
    classpath = files('../server/proto-gen/java/')
    options.compilerArgs = ["-sourcepath", "$projectDir/../server/proto-gen/java/"]
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0-alpha-2'
    compileGrpc.execute()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your dependencies like

```
dependencies {
        classpath files('server/proto-gen/java/com/myApp/')
    }
```

This will accept relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Simply including the path to the `src` sourceset for the project would include them within the compilation:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = [java.srcDirs, 'server/proto-gen/java']
        }
    }
}
```

You'll be able to see the src files/directories included within the Android View/Project Explorer on the right side and edit the files directly.